# Shiny: Why using a temporay variable for output on the server side fails?

Tags: r, function, expression, shiny

Here is a simple shiny app that works :

`ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  numericInput("mymun", "enter a number",0),
  textOutput("mytext") 
))
```

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)
test <-  function(input, output){
  renderText(paste("this is my number:",input$mymun))
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  output$mytext <- test(input, output)
})
```

However if I put the result of the function call in a temporary variable the app fails

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)
test <-  function(input, output){
  renderText(paste("this is my number:",input$mymun))
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  tmp <- test(input, output)
  output$mytext <- tmp
})
```

The error message is :

```
Error in substitute(value)[[2]] : 
 object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Does anyone could gives clues about why the second one fails and why the first does not ?
I guess this is due to expression processing and the reactive logic of shiny server, but I am not clear about it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to actually figure this out is to re-read http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/lessons/Lesson-6/ + http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/lessons/Lesson-7/ + http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping to ensure you fully understand reactivity and scoping (no sense posting the seminal tutorial text in SO).

To get something close to what you're trying to do, you'd need to do the following in `server.R`:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 

  test <- reactive({
    return(paste("this is my number:",input$mymun))
  })

  output$mytext <- renderText({
    tmp <- test()
    return(tmp)
  })

})
```

Comment: It's clear that using a reactive function is the proper way to do it, but could you explain what exactly messes up OPs example, as his question isn't "how to get this to work", but rather "why does example 1 work whereas example 2 doesn't".

Comment: That would be the "let's not repeat what's in the tutorial" since they explain it fairly well there.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I am clear now on why the second code fails. However, it is not that straightforward to understand why the first code does not fail.  I guess that `output$mytext` is somehow coerced to an observer but that's still unclear.

Comment: @hrbrmstr please, can you repost the links to tutorials? They are unavailable now. Thank you.